# Sharing Files and Resources through 2 Routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan, home-networking

I need help setting up the routers below so I can access the WD My Cloud using *Laptop 1*.

My current network layout is:

- **Huawei  EchoLife HG8245H** (IP: `192.168.100.1`)

  - **Port 1:** WAN - Edimax BR6675ND
  - **Port 2:** LAN - Laptop 1
  - **Port 3:** LAN - IP TV
- **Edimax BR6675ND** (IP: `192.168.2.1`)

  - **Port 1:** WD My Cloud
  - **Port 2:** Laptop 2

I can access the *WD My Cloud* [Edimax] and internet with *Laptop 2* [Edimax], however, *Laptop 1* [Huawei] can't access the *WD My Cloud*, but can access the internet; both Huawei's and Edimax's WiFi works fine.

Comment: Generally, the `192.168.100.0/24` subnet should be avoided, as most modems use this subnet for their simple local DNS server.  Unless the devices connected to each router need to be firewalled from each other, place both routers within the same subnet (i.e. assign Huawei router IP `192.168.2.2`) and configure it as a DHCP client of the Edimax router, assigning the Huawei router a static IP on the Edimax router (or vice versa)

Comment: This is another instance of the very common "two routers chained" question. Search this site for examples on a) setting up static routes, or b) merging both subnets into one.